# How to merge multiple powerpoint files into one file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, merge, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

Is there an easy way to combine multiple powerpoint files into one single file?

Under [ms dos for binary files you can copy them using /b](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/71161) or according to [this SO question just use copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764558/in-ms-dos-copying-several-files-to-one-file)

```
 copy /b <source1> + <source2> [....] <targetfile>
 // or
 copy *.csv new.csv
```

I tried the later `copy *.pptx new.pptx` but this did not work - the resulting pptx was empty.  The first approach using `copy /b` requires to enter each file name which is cumbersome and i did not try.

Do you have any ideas how i could sovle this?

Comment: Is it an option to do this by hand? Since there is a function for doing this inside PowerPoint.

Comment: Depends how comfortable it is - can i select multiple files at once or do i have to iterate the steps for each file?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/merge-powerpoint-ppt-files/) you have to do it manually for each file. **But** if you're not going to edit the big presentation after creating it, the easiest way would be to convert all files to PDF (you can find a tool that does that for 100 files automatically) and then combine those PDF-files as one big file (done that a thousand times with i.e. Adobe Acrobat)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but you can't do it with Binary Appending.

**Why...??**
Because a CSV is a comma separated values file, which allows data to be saved in a table structured format. CSVs look like a garden-variety spreadsheet but with a .csv extension. So when you append them, you can still use them in excel. But .pptx have different formats that are not so simple. hence Binary appending won't work.

The following code will insert **all slides** from all presentations in the **same folder** as the currently active presentation (but won't try to insert slides from the current presentation into itself). **(Personally Tested)**

Follow the steps:

1. Create a New Folder.
2. For appending Mutiple Files, Save the current file in the new folder in which you want to insert slides from other files.
3. Copy all the other .pptx or .ppt files to the new folder
   Open the document in which you want to add files.
4. Now Press ALT+F11 to start the VBA editor.
5. Or choose File | Options |
   Customize Ribbon and put a checkmark next to Developer in the listbox
   under Customize Ribbon. Close the options dialog box, click the
   Developer tab then click Visual Basic to start the editor.
6. In the VBA editor, make sure that your presentation is highlighted in the left-hand pane.
   Choose Insert, Module from the menu bar to insert a new code module into your    project.
7. Paste this Code & Change "`*.PPT`" to "`*.PPTX`" or whatever if necessary

   ```vb
   Sub InsertAllSlides()
   '  Insert all slides from all presentations in the same folder as this one
   '  INTO this one; do not attempt to insert THIS file into itself, though.

       Dim vArray() As String
       Dim x As Long

       ' Change "*.PPT" to "*.PPTX" or whatever if necessary:
       EnumerateFiles ActivePresentation.Path & "\", "*.PPT", vArray

       With ActivePresentation
           For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
               If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
                   .Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x), .Slides.Count
               End If
           Next
       End With

   End Sub

   Sub EnumerateFiles(ByVal sDirectory As String, _
       ByVal sFileSpec As String, _
       ByRef vArray As Variant)
       ' collect all files matching the file spec into vArray, an array of strings

       Dim sTemp As String
       ReDim vArray(1 To 1)

       sTemp = Dir$(sDirectory & sFileSpec)
       Do While Len(sTemp) > 0
           ' NOT the "mother ship" ... current presentation
           If sTemp <> ActivePresentation.Name Then
               ReDim Preserve vArray(1 To UBound(vArray) + 1)
               vArray(UBound(vArray)) = sDirectory & sTemp
           End If
           sTemp = Dir$
       Loop

   End Sub
   ```
8. To make sure there are no serious syntax problems with the code, choose Debug, Compile from the menu bar.
9. If there is an error check the code again, else click the Run button.
10. the Slides will be added to the opened document.

**NOTE :** Background Pictures & some other elements are not added when slides are added from another file.

**See & Learn More From :**

- [Insert all slides from a group of presentations into the current
  presentation](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00746_Insert_all_slides_from_a_group_of_presentations_into_the_current_presentation.htm)
- [How do I use VBA code in
  PowerPoint](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00033_How_do_I_use_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In powerpoint 2013 this has to be repeated for every file. I am looking to do it in a loop for n files at once.

Comment: Try the macro technique. Given at the bottom.

Comment: See I re-edited the whole thing, It works Confirmed my testing it.

Comment: See you can use this one too, But I am getting some errors while compiling it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316459/programmatically-combine-slides-from-multiple-presentations-into-a-single-presen