# Merge PowerPoint Presentations Slide By Slide as Animation

Tags: vba, microsoft-office, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I have 12 PowerPoint presentations (one for each month) with same number of slides and each slide contains similar reporting info/trends/tables for the corresponding month. I would like to merge all 12 of them into a single Presentation, with each slide contains 12 months of slidepack added as animations. Basically, this will help to show the trend month-by-month for the whole year.
Is it possible using some PowerPoint magic or using VBA? I have found a VBA macro that merges them into single one, but it merges file 1 + file 2 + .... + file 12 in sequential order.

Is there a way to keep same number of slides, but merge them slide by slide as animation? Below schematic shows what I am trying to achieve.

[image: merge PowerPoint slides]

Comment: Your illustration makes it appear that you want a final pressie with Pres1Slide1, Pres1Slide2...PresNSlide1,PresNSlide2 etc. IOW, insert all of the slides from each presentation into a new presentation in order, done.  If instead you want the results "interleaved", as Pres1Slide1,Pres2Slide1,Pres3Slide1,Pres1Slide2,Pres2Slide2 ... that's a different matter. The first is so simple and quick to do manually that it's not worth writing a macro for. If the second is what you want, I have a bit of VBA that might do.

Answer (score 0):

Open the presentations side by side (https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-merge-slides-in-powerpoint) and proceed by drag and drop, then set the animation.
Otherwise,I think the simpliest way is to export to pdf. After you can manage it (with https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/merge-pdf.html for example).
It seems a bit complex to do without some work.

You can also adapt (I'm a linux user, so I can't test) adapt the part InsertAllSlides [How to merge multiple powerpoint files into one file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1081012/how-to-merge-multiple-powerpoint-files-into-one-file) like that:

Sub InsertAllSlides()
'  Insert all slides from all presentations in the same folder as this one
'  INTO this one; do not attempt to insert THIS file into itself, though.

```
Dim vArray() As String
Dim x As Long

' Change "*.PPT" to "*.PPTX" or whatever if necessary:
EnumerateFiles ActivePresentation.Path & "\", "*.PPT", vArray

Dim pagecount As Integer
pagecount = [number of slides par document]
For page = 1 To pagecount
    With ActivePresentation
        For x = 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If Len(vArray(x)) > 0 Then
                .Slides.InsertFromFile vArray(x), page, page + 1
            End If
        Next
   End With
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks. I know that we can do that side by side, but I have 12 of these, so I am looking for an automated way to do this. Thank you for you suggestion.